# Looking for resources: like C doc for reading files and their attributes? (On Linux)

Tags: files, c

Looking for resources: like C doc (something like JavaDoc for C on Linux would be cool) for reading files and their attributes?

I'm working on recursively reading in files.  I can get a list of files in a directory, with some simple code that uses `readdir( DIR* )`, but I'm looking for some code that I can, in general, browse through.

I'm kind of new to Linux -- so maybe man pages are the way to go here, but since man pages typically aren't linked together (like hyperlinks), I'm looking for resources that describe relationships between C structs and function for file IO.  I'm wondering if I need to go as far as understanding `inode` stuff?

Comment: Man pages *are* linked together, the `man` command typically doesn't allow the links to be interactive.

Comment: And I just pressed `q` to try to close this tab. Thanks :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well-linked one is e.g. GNU libc documentation:

http://info2html.sourceforge.net/cgi-bin/info2html-demo/info2html?%28libc.info.gz%29Top

(or its equivalent installed locally)

See "file system interface" from the top page.

Man pages carry hyperlinks but you need proper man browser instead of default one. For console, try [pinfo](http://pinfo.alioth.debian.org), it provides very simple Lynx-like interface.

Comment: Sweet, I didn't know about `pinfo`.